# Insert -l to each variable of set in makefile

Tags: makefile

I write makefile.

I have a variable set, which is the library I want to link to:

```
LIBS = core highgui
```

I want to make **LIBS** a **VAR** in some way:

```
#...some way, input is LIBS, output is VAR
VAR = -lcore -lhighgui
```

What is the some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is easier, just use [`addprefix`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#File-Name-Functions):

```
VAR = $(addprefix -l,$(LIBS))
```